# How to get number of opened file descriptors for user

Tags: linux, users, non-root-user, open-files

I know about `lsof` and `ls /proc/*/fd` but none of them are atomic AFAIK. Because in the latter case I would need to get all pids for user and then filter by them and by that time some of the file descriptors could be closed.

Maybe there is some system call for that or something, because obviously OS tracks that number as it would refuse to create FD if max limit for user is exhausted.

Comment: Are you sure that `it would refuse to create FD if max limit for user is exhausted`? The [setrlimit/getrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrlimit) system calls work a `per-process` base. [diskquota](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-disk-quotas.html#s2-disk-quotas-assigning-user) works on a `per filesystem` base. AFAIK, there is no API that works on a `per user` base.

Comment: Well, there is a limit for every user. If it wouldn't refuse to create file when it's exhausted then this limit is useless, right?

Comment: either `lsof`(with non atomic constraint) or read kernel sources and build your own utility. A good question anyway.

Comment: @user1685095 There is a limit for each process of a specified user not for each user. If a user has an hard limit of `RLIMIT_NOFILE` set to 100, she'll can have two processes with 99 open files (198 in total).

Comment: @andcoz And how much precesses are available for user?

Comment: The answer for this will be OS specific and will likely require direct reading of kernel data structures. (Or the ability to pause all of a user's processes.)  What OSs are you interested in?

Comment: @user1685095 It depends on the value of `RLIMIT_NPROC`. Read the [setrlimit/getrlimit man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrlimit), it is very clear or the section [limit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) (or [ulimit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)) of the man page of your shell of choice.

Comment: @user1685095 Sorry, I should have wrote in bold that my comments are **linux** oriented. The name and the parameters of the sys-calls can change on other OSes.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Redhat

Answer (score 1):

I haven't made an intensive search, but I don't think what you're looking for exists on Linux. Opening a file descriptor doesn't take any global lock, only a per-process lock, so on a multicore machine whatever you'd be using to count the number of open file descriptors could be running literally at the same time that other threads is opening or closing files on other cores.

Linux doesn't have a global limit on the total number of open files. There's no explicit per-user limit either. There's a per-user limit on *processes*, and a per-process limit on file descriptor numbers, which indirectly imposes a limit on open files per user, but that isn't explicitly tracked.

Exploring `/proc` (which is what `lsof` does under the hood) is as good as it gets. `/proc` is the Linux API to get information about processes.

Comment: What does /etc/security/limits.conf is doing if there's no limit on open files for user

Comment: @user1685095 It sets limits that are not limits on open files per user.

Comment: You answering on what it isn't. And I'm asking what it is.

Comment: http://gerardnico.com/wiki/linux/limits.conf you can see there that there is a limit for open file descriptors. Which is exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: @user1685095 As several of us have told you already, this is a **per process** limit, not per user. `limits.conf` defines different values for each user, but what that means is that *each* process run by the user has this limit, not that the limit is for the total number of files open by a process run by the user.